# Joining lines until a "terminating" string is reached

Tags: notepad++, regex

In a file, I have data like the following:

```
123
456
789
---
101112
131415
161718
192021
------
222223242526
27282930313233
-----------------------
```

I need to change the lines to look like this:

```
123 456 789 ---
101112 131415 161718 192021 ------
222223242526 27282930313233 -----------------------
```

i.e. up to a specific string (a sequence of hypens) the lines are to be merged.

I've tried many methods, but I can't get it to work.

I have around 15000 lines in my actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job, this will replace all linebreaks that are not preceded by a dash with a space:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!-)\R`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!-)  : negative lookbehind, make sure we don't have a dash before
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123 456 789 ---
101112 131415 161718 192021 ------
222223242526 27282930313233 -----------------------
```